# VS2017 MFC Warning: no message line prompt for ID 0xE001

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++

I am getting a strange warning in Microsoft Visual Studio 2017. The warning is shown in the output window of VS2017 and it reads:

`d:\agent\_work\2\s\src\vctools\vc7libs\ship\atlmfc\src\mfc\winfrm.cpp(1628) : AppMsg - Warning: no message line prompt for ID 0xE001.`

The given path does not exist on my computer. I found the file winfrm.cpp in a different folder and line 1628 of this file reads:

`TRACE(traceAppMsg, 0, "Warning: no message line prompt for ID 0x%04X.\n", nID);`

But this does not help me. Any ideas how to resolve the warning?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turned out that the warning resulted due to the fact that the property prompt of the menu items were set to "". Setting the property to " " made the warning disappear. I converted the ID from Hex to Dec: 0xE001 -> 57345 and changed the stringtable in the file Main.rc to:

```
STRINGTABLE
BEGIN
57345    " "
END
```

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem: the message was not being displayed for a single toolbar button, and the same warning was being generated.

It turned out that the message entry for *another* button had got into the U.S. English string table (with all the standard MFC strings). I have no idea how that happened, but moving it to the other string table fixed the problem.

(Note: it was no *conscious* choice of mine to have two string tables!)

N.B. This is no attempt to deny the OP's solution.